# Flutter reposition keyboard down

Tags: android, flutter, android-wear-2.0

I am having problems with a textfield pop up keyboard not displaying its input correctly on an Android Wear app.

I have reduced code to

```
return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: new TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        maxLines: null,
      ),
    )
  );
```

However, as you will see below, the line normally at the top (which would display what is currently being typed as well as the submit button), is off the top of the screen, so it's impossible to submit any entry.

It looks like the whole keyboard should be shifted down one line, and if I use a normal Android Wear app keyboard, the keyboard is indeed one or two lines lower.

Is there any solution to repositioning the keyboard lower, or any other solution ?

[image: Wear 2 image]